# How to make a temporal variogram

Tags: r, temporal

How can I make a temporal variogram of a set of 20 datetime values of rainfall with a frequency of 15 minutes? How should I transfer the datetime values to temporal distances?

```
          datetime       R
0  2011-08-05 14:45:00   0.000
1  2011-08-05 15:00:00   0.000
2  2011-08-05 15:15:00   0.000
3  2011-08-05 15:30:00   0.000
4  2011-08-05 15:45:00   4.318
5  2011-08-05 16:00:00   3.302
6  2011-08-05 16:15:00   6.604
7  2011-08-05 16:30:00   0.000
...
19 2011-08-05 19:30:00   0.000
```

I solved already some spatial and directional variogram in Rstudio, but it is hard to solve temporal variogram. Have anyone some suggestions?

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output? Can you provide a reference for the type of plot you are after?

Comment: a plotted variogram like this: [link](http://pubs.rsc.org/services/images/RSCpubs.ePlatform.Service.FreeContent.ImageService.svc/ImageService/Articleimage/2006/EM/b605440d/b605440d-f4.gif)

Comment: Does anyone have some suggestion?